# Две функции объединить в одну

Tags: javascript, функции, события

Есть две функции, которые вызываются при клике на кнопки, эти функции работают как надо. Нужно сделать событие input, чтобы данные сразу выводились на страницу, если я логику первой функции смогу скопировать, то вторую функцию я уже не могу сделать. Допустим я введу в инпут 12, мне выведется слова, которые больше длины 12, дальше я захожу стереть и написать en, что должно выводить слова у которых есть en - тут уже не работает. Как можно эти две функции сделать одной и повесить на событие input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим f - ваша функция, в которой будут объединены функции secondButton и firstButton. Различие их выполнения заключается в типе аргумента, т.е введя
12 вы ищите длину, а введя 'en' вы ищете конкретное совпадение в подстроке.
Различие только в типах передаваемого аргумента. Но, есть один нюанс. У вас значения берутся из инпута, что уже делает все типы строками и проверка через `typeof value` не поможет.
Есть несколько решений данное проблемы.

1. Сделать чекбокс/селектор с текстом на типе "Поиск по длинне" и "Поиск по строке". Далее нам нужно просто брать значение из чекбокса/слайдера и обрабатывать функционал по разному
2. Конвертировать значение из инпута используя Number(value) и далее делать проверка на тип NaN. Если же будет NaN, то будем искать подстроку, а если преобразование получиться, то поиск по длине.
   **Второй способ я не рекомендую, т.к это очень костыльно и будет непонятно для пользователя**